# MySQL search engine - AND keywords

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a search query between a table of key terms and pages.

Consider the following tables.

PAGES

```
page_id  page_name
1        cats
2        dogs
3        humans
```

KEYWORDS

```
key_id   key_name   key_page_id
1        purz       1
2        puzy       1
3        ruff       2
4        john       3
5        purz       3
```

Where the search terms are purz AND puzy I want the query results to return only page id 1.

```
SELECT page_id FROM PAGES, KEYWORDS 
WHERE (key_name='purz OR key_name='puzy') AND key_page_id = page_id;
```

Returns

```
page_id
1
3
```

I'm wanting

```
page_id
1
```

Because only purz AND puzy both are linked to Cats.

Comment: Also I have considered it might be more efficient to create a temporary Keywords table updated from Keywords where I can guaranty uniqueness. I'm also thinking scalability here.

Comment: You do not need temporary table, only add a unique index on 2 fields: key_name and key_page_id in KEYWORDS table. This will garantee you that you do not have the same keyword for the same page twice. ALTER TABLE `KEYWORDS` ADD UNIQUE (
`key_name` ,
`key_page_id`
)

Comment: Sorry, i know my example is abstract and perhaps did not specify the need for these duplicate keywords

Answer (score 1):

I believe to accomplish this, you have to join on the keywords table twice:

```
SELECT p.page_id
FROM pages p
JOIN keywords k ON (k.key_page_id = p.page_id)
JOIN keywords k2 ON (k2.key_page_id = p.page_id)
WHERE k.key_name='purz'
    AND k2.key_name='puzy';
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this really works, but you could try to join the keywords table with itself for each searchterm, eg something like:

```
SELECT searchterm1.key_page_id as page_id FROM KEYWORDS searchterm1 
INNER JOIN KEYWORDS searchterm2 
ON (searchterm1.key_page_id = searchterm2.key_page_id) 
WHERE searchterm1.key_name='purz' AND searchterm2.key_name='puzy';
```

you wouldn't even need to join with the PAGES table,  unless you need page_name returned as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.page_id, COUNT( key_id ) AS keyword_all
FROM PAGES p
JOIN KEYWORDS ON key_page_id = page_id
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING keyword_all = (
  SELECT COUNT( key_id ) AS found_k
    FROM KEYWORDS
    WHERE key_page_id = p.page_id
      AND (
      key_name = 'purz'
      OR key_name = 'puzy'
    )
  )
```

What I did here is to get only pages which total number of keywords match the keywords that we look for.

This way you do not need to join multiple times. Only change the WHERE condition in the subquery according to the keywords that you look for.